# info window for marker

Tags: google-maps

I use google maps marker. I have array of info to be shown with info window. I have tried like  this,

```
markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
{

    info = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
    GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", function(info) {
          this.openInfoWindowHtml(info);                      
    });
}
```

`openInfoWindowHtml(info)` must be displayed for each and every marker. I need to get the info window displayed.

thanks
v.srinath

Answer (score 2):

Check below scripts, make sure to add the google map with api

```
    // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    function init()
    {
    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation    //javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
    zoom: 4,
```

`// The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.985448,52.7994103),
// Main map location
  navigationControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  draggable: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
},

// How you would like to style the map. 
// This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
styles: []
};

// Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
// We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the 
<body>
var mapElement = document.getElementById('googlemap');
// Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

// address content Kuwait
var location1 = '<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">'+
'</div>'+
'<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Location1 name</h1>'+
'<div id="bodyContent">'+
'<p> Location 1 content' +                        
'</p>'+                        
'</div>'+
'</div>';
var infolocation1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: location1
}); 
// Location Kuwait
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.363765,47.966278),
map: map,
title: ''
});
marker1.addListener('click', function() {
infolocation1.open(map, marker1);
});


// address content Kuwait
var location2 = '<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">'+
'</div>'+
'<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">
Location2 name</h1>'+
'<div id="bodyContent">'+
'<p> Location 2 content' +                        
'</p>'+                        
'</div>'+
'</div>';
var infolocation2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: location2
}); 
// Location Kuwait
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.363765,47.966278),
map: map,
title: ''
});
marker2.addListener('click', function() {
infolocation2.open(map, marker2);
});



}
</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code at this line `GEvent.addListener(marker[i], "click", function(info) {` there is not such array `marker`

Fixed code is

```
markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
{

    info = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
    GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", function() {
          markers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(info);                      
    });
}
```

Comment: antyrat, sorry for the spelling mistake. It is indeed the GEvent.addListener(markers[i],..) and now I edited it. still it does n't work.

thanks
v.srinath

Comment: Can you show XML file example? I don't see where you create marker. It must be something like this: var marker = new GMarker(point); where var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);

Comment: <markers>
    <marker name="Restaurant Name" address="7643 qwert" lat="50.8343" lng="-100.34534"/>
    <marker name="Restaurant name" address="2345 mnbv" lat="51.6564" lng="-100.345"/>

</markers>

Comment: geocoder.getLocations(.........
markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
location3 = <lat, lng> //from geocoder
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)  { location2 = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),               parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
if(distance_in_mile(locaiton2,location3) < 5) {
marker[i] = new GMarker(location2);                     map.addOverlay(marker[i]);
info = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
GEvent.addListener(marker[i], "click", function() {
this.openInfoWindowHtml(info);
});